# How can I fix my homepage showing a 403 error?

Tags: cpanel, http-status-code-403

I keep getting a 403 error on my homepage, despite having all my permissions set to allow public to read. I'm not using any plugins, I'm not using Wordpress, and though my site is routed through Cloudflare it goes through to my hosting provider's 403 page (I haven't created my own). I've tried 755 and 644 and I keep getting the same thing. How can I fix this?
(The website is alexbelman.com)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons depending on your hosting environment and a bit more detailed info from you about your hosting setup would help. For example - is your site on a server running Linux? cPanel?

But maybe this info can help you in the meantime:

If you're sure you have the correct permissions on folders (in most cases your public_html folder should be 750, all folders within the public_html folder in most cases should be 755, and files should be 644) then probably the first two things I would check would be:

- Make sure you have an index file in your public_html folder - some examples would be index.html , index.htm , index.php , or on some hosts a default.html is used. If there is no index file in the folder that serves your site, server security configs will often present a 403 while protecting the sensitive contents of your hosting account from being viewed.
- If you're sure you have an index file in your public facing folder, then check the contents of the .htaccess file in your public_html folder, since an errant rule or line of code in your htaccess is a common cause for a 403

If you can post the contents of your .htaccess file here someone here or possibly myself can spot anything that shouldn't be there or is incorrect.

Also, since you're using CloudFlare you should take a look at their Quick Fix suggestions here - https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-403-forbidden/53308